# convert sql xml datatype to table

Tags: sql-server-2008, openxml, sqlxml, sql-server-openxml

Given the SQL...

```
declare @xmlDoc xml
set @xmlDoc = '<people>
  <person PersonID="8" LastName="asdf" />
  <person PersonID="26" LastName="rtert" />
  <person PersonID="33" LastName="dfgh" />
  <person PersonID="514" LastName="ukyy" />
</people>'
```

What would be the sql to convert that xml into a table of two columns PersonID and LastName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T.c.query('.').value('(//@PersonID)[1]', 'int'),
    T.c.query('.').value('(//@LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/people/person') T(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select T.X.value('@PersonID', 'int') as PersonID,
       T.X.value('@LastName', 'nvarchar(50)') as LastName
from @xmlDoc.nodes('/people/person') as T(X)
```